# Nuxt 3 - automatic redirect when a slash is missing in the url

Tags: redirect, nuxtjs3, trailing-slash

In our NUXT 3 application, there is a redirect for some reason when there is no slash at the end of the url. For example, when entering the address https://www.example.com/pricing, we get an automatic redirect from pricing to pricing/. Which is bad for SEO. We use a default nuxt config and we did not change anything for routes. Don't you know why this is happening? Thank you

[image]

We already tried to solve it by setting the route to trailingSlash false, which should be the default. Also setting route config strict or global middleware.